# Is higher jerk always better for reducing cycle time?

Tags: robotic-arm

I'm interested in decreasing the cycle time (time to execute a given task) of a robotic arm. As in the title, are there any downsides to maximising the joint jerks of the robot?

Naively, increasing the rate of acceleration should lead to shorter cycle times. Perhaps are there long term negative effects on the wear and tear of the robot?

Comment: I think you mean decrease cycle time. Can you edit your post if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't directly worked with robot arms, but I would think that too much jerk is a bad idea. I think it could increase the wear and tear of the joints and also affect final precision.

Anyways, [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0736584512000981) sheds some insights on this topic.

> High jerk of the robot joint can heavily excite the resonance
> frequencies of the body structure, creating vibrations, and slow down
> the tracking speed, as well as affect the tracking precision